# How to add hadoop dependency via Maven? I have hadoop installed and present in my IDE project library

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, intellij-idea

- I have hadoop installed on my system(I am using Mac 10.7)
- I am using Intellij IDEA as IDE and my hadoop project has listed hadoop*.jar as dependency
- When I do `mvn install`, it fails with the following error

> ```
> (master) $ mvn clean install
> [INFO] Scanning for projects...
> [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
> [ERROR]   
> [ERROR]   The project groupId:hadoop:master-SNAPSHOT (/Users/me/code/p/java/hadoop-programs/hadoop-programs/pom.xml)
> ```
>
> has 1 error
>       [ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:jar must be omitted. This field may only
>   be specified for a dependency with system scope. @ line 18, column 25
>       [ERROR] 
>       [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>       [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>       [ERROR] 
>       [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>       [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException

I make changed to my `pom.xml` as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop</artifactId>
    <version>master-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <systemPath>/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.0.3/libexec/hadoop-core-1.0.3.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

But still same error, How do I resolve this in Maven?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.20.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

A lot of the stuff in hadoop-core have moved to hadoop-client in newer versions, use -

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```